# Creating a unique ID column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I hope I can explain this clearly. I have a 3 month daily `timeseries` data set that has `multiple` attribute values for each `ID`. Values under each attribute are stored in different columns.

Sample data

```
ID     Date     Var1    Var2
279557 1/1/2020 1       2
279557 1/2/2020 3       4
280485 1/1/2020 5       6
288785 1/2/2020 7       8
```

The purpose is to aggregate the `ID` value under each `Var` for each `month`, and then plot `timeseries` line plots for each aggregated `ID` for under each `Var`.

I first thought of doing a `pivot long`

```
  library(dplyr)
    library(tidyverse)
    

ID = c("297557", "279557", "280485", "280485")
Date = c("1/1/2020", "1/2/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/2/2020")
Var1 = c("1", "3", "5", "7")
Var2 = c("2", "4", "6", "8")

df = data.frame(ID, Date, Var1, Var2)

        df= df%>% 
          pivot_longer(-c(ID, Date))
```

Output

```
ID     Date     Value  
279557 1/1/2020 1 
279557 1/1/2020 2
279557 1/2/2020 3
279557 1/1/2020 4 
280485 1/1/2020 5       
280485 1/1/2020 6
280485 1/2/2020 7
280485 1/2/2020 8
```

Now in order to group (for ggplot2) each `Var` value under each `ID`, I am thinking of creating another unique `ID` column called `Pixel`. The unique `ID` should be such that, for example, for the first two values of `Var1` for `297557`, I can have a unique ID like `ID1.Var1`under the pixel column.

```
Pixel     ID     Date     Value  
ID1.Var1  279557 1/1/2020 1 
ID1.Var2  279557 1/1/2020 2
ID1.Var1  279557 1/1/2020 3
ID1.Var2  279557 1/2/2020 4 
ID2.Var1  280485 1/1/2020 5       
ID2.Var2  280485 1/1/2020 6
ID2.Var1  280485 1/2/2020 7
ID2.Var2  280485 1/2/2020 8
```

Now I can use `ggplot`

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x= Date, y=Value, group = Pixel)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("")
```

How can I create a unique `Pixel` column `automatically` without having to manually type each unique ID under the `Pixel` column in `R` using `dplyr`?

Comment: You are not trying to aggregate (at least not at first; you might be aggregating later and if so you would ask another question). You are trying to rearrange. Look at `pivot_longer`

Comment: Yes I have already done the `pivot_longer` step, and posted the `output` in the question. I am right now stuck on creating another unique `ID` column called `Pixel`.

Comment: Your suggested output likely needs attention to detail.  The second Pixel entry should be ID1.Var2 and the third one should be ID1.Var1 and I think there are a couple of otehr errors further down. You also should post the code to create the initial object and the code you used to modify it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I have fixed that.

Comment: @Park, the condition for `ID1.Var1` = `279557.Var1`. `Var1` is the column name for the first attribute. . Similarly for  `ID`1.Var2` = `279557.Var2`. I just created a `Pixel` column myself by manually typing it for this question to show what I want in that column. I think I need to add more clarity to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, Date)) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Pixel = paste0(c("ID",as.integer(as.factor(ID)),".",name), collapse = "")) %>% select(-name)


  ID     Date     value Pixel   
  <chr>  <chr>    <chr> <chr>   
1 279557 1/1/2020 1     ID1.Var1
2 279557 1/1/2020 2     ID1.Var2
3 279557 1/2/2020 3     ID1.Var1
4 279557 1/2/2020 4     ID1.Var2
5 280485 1/1/2020 5     ID1.Var1
6 280485 1/1/2020 6     ID1.Var2
7 280485 1/2/2020 7     ID1.Var1
8 280485 1/2/2020 8     ID1.Var2
```

## Update

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, Date)) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Pixel = paste0(c(ID,".",name), collapse = "")) %>% select(-name)

  ID     Date     value Pixel      
  <chr>  <chr>    <chr> <chr>      
1 279557 1/1/2020 1     279557.Var1
2 279557 1/1/2020 2     279557.Var2
3 279557 1/2/2020 3     279557.Var1
4 279557 1/2/2020 4     279557.Var2
5 280485 1/1/2020 5     280485.Var1
6 280485 1/1/2020 6     280485.Var2
7 280485 1/2/2020 7     280485.Var1
8 280485 1/2/2020 8     280485.Var2
```

Comment: Hi Park, I just realized that `ID1.Var1` sounds vague, so it would be better to actually combine the actual `ID` value with `Var1` and `Var2` under the `Pixel` column. Something like this `279557.Var1` and `279557.Var2`  and so on. Can I please update this question to reflect this  and you can slightly modify your answer?

Comment: @Mandalorian I update the code :)